# Bash comparison between strings - equal but not equal for it

Tags: string, bash, if-statement

I just wanted to do a really simple comparison between 2 strings in Bash :

```
stat=`curl -Is $url | head -n 1` 
echo $stat
if [ "$stat" = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ];then
    echo "$symbol is OK"
    echo $stat
    valide=$(( $valide + 1 ))
else
    echo "$symbol is 404"
    echo $stat
    err=$(( $err + 1 ))
fi
```

But even if "stat" is completely the same, the result stay that it does not equal :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
AAA is 404
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

How can i modify my code ?

I had also a lot of errors with "/" ("unexpected operator", ...) in the string before arrive to this code sample, and i tried many different approaches like contains (*"200"*) with the same result.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Try `echo "|$stat|"`. I'll bet there's some extra spaces.

Comment: @Barmar Probably a trailing carriage return.

Comment: @melpomene Yes, that's exactly what it is

Comment: Yep, i didn't think about it, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curl output includes a `CR` at the end of the lines, you need to remove it.

```
stat=`curl -Is $url | head -n 1 | tr -d '\r'`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think there might be trailing characters (which you don't mind) then use `[[` pattern matching instead:

```
# Try not to use `` anymore, backticks are hard to read
stat=$(curl -Is $url | head -n 1)  

# When debugging, use some sort of delimiter which shows leading or trailing whitespace     
echo "<$stat>"                          

# Variables inside [[ don't need to be quoted
# Adding a trailing * allows optional trailing characters
if [[ $stat == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"* ]];then
    echo "$symbol is OK"
    echo $stat
    $(( valide++ ))          # You don't need the "$", just the variable name
else
    echo "$symbol is 404"
    echo $stat
    $(( err++ ))             # using a $ in (( )) can change the scan sequence
fi
```